# Find the 'source' value of image (img) where its Id is dynamically changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code

```
<img id="simple_captcha-ad089ff4819" src="/simple_captcha?code=a35401d">`
```

In this, `img` tag's `id` is not static. It keeps on changing for every new action.

For the next action, its `id` can be "simple_captcha-sfw454sdfs". 
So, based on these id, I have to fetch its `src` value.

Comment: is it only one image, what is the surrounding code, why is the id changing?

Comment: Actually It is Captcha. So, it is keep on changing .Here, I made it simple to understand . Actually code will look like this                                                <img id="simple_captcha-ad089ff4819" src="http://0.0.0.0:3000/simple_captcha?code=ad089ff481992354011b88750fb4b465d6dca7ed&time=1472239355" alt="captcha">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a selector that matches the beginning of the ID.

```
var src = $("img[id^=simple_captcha-]").attr('src');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the image and select her with the class name. `$('.image-class-name').attr('src');`